# Power of NVIDIA GPU out of limits (Nvidia A100)

Tags: gpu, cuda, energy

I am executing a CUDA kernel in my A100 GPU and I've realized that the power consumption at some points is higher than `nvidia-smi` given range:

[image]

The picture has been taken from `nvtop`.

Is it something that I should be worry about?

Comment: "burst" performance has, for at least the last 5 years, been a fluid thing in computing. Intel processors have "turbo boost" where they self-overclock depending on thermal limits and power capabilities of the chip itself. Those overclocks are also time and instantaneous temperature dependent so a "cold" chip will overclock higher and that clock speed will drop over time as the device warms up. I would be surprised if Nvidia do not have similar capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The only worrisome aspect is the temperature, which seems to be at an unimpressive
52°C. This doesn't make sense if the power draw is truly above the max.

So, take your pick. Either:

- The power draw figure is false
- The temperature reported is false
- `nvtop` is not working correctly with your GPU.

I would suggest verifying the temperature using other applications.
If they also report the same readings, then you don't need to worry.
Check both CPU and GPU and motherboard.

Useful references:

- [How To Check CPU Temperature in Ubuntu Linux](https://itsfoss.com/check-laptop-cpu-temperature-ubuntu/)
- [4 Useful Tools to Monitor CPU and GPU Temperature in Ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/monitor-cpu-and-gpu-temperature-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use nvtop for an easier monitorization. Data is the same that in nvidia-smi.

Comment: There is also above a fourth option, that the card is reporting false values. In any case, I would suggest keeping an eye on temperature readings, but otherwise, as long as the computer doesn't crash, believe in those temperature readings.

Answer (score 1):

The power draw of a GPU is uneven - it has spikes and lows. The specified power draw of a card is ment to be read as "rolling average over one second" during which time it can fluctuate over and belo that value - this is one of the reasons why PSU specs are recommended to be way over the sum of specified component power draw in a GPU-heavy rig.

`nvidia-smi` and friends report not the rolling average, but the momentary power draw, which can of course exceed the specified value. If you randomly sample your GPU power draw over a statistically relevant sample, you are very likely to see a value very close to specs.